# quantum coin walk on a regular 3D grid graph

Tags: quantum-walks

I am trying to apply the quantum coin walk on a 3D grid, with 3 Hadamard coins. So there would be 6 different directions at each steps and there is 8 possible coin outcomes.

I can't seem to get symmetric results after 3 steps. Is it simply not possible to have a probability distribution which is symmetric with such a coin? Is it possible with a DFT coin?

Thank you

ps the implementation is based on http://susan-stepney.blogspot.com/2014/02/mathjax.html and the position vector captures a 3D grid.